# How can i prevent fragment to reload when BottomNavitionView item is already selected

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, bottomnavigationview, android-navigation

I'm using bottomNavigation view with Android Navigation, but when a menu item is already selected and I click again on it, the fragment is reloading. I tried to disable it but I didn'tfind any way to do it well

Here is my code : 
**navigation_menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/companyProfileFragment"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_company"
        android:title="Mon entreprise"
    />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/companyTeamFragment"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_team"
        android:title="Mon équipe" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/companyDayOrdersFragment"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_week_menu"
        android:title="Notre journée" />

</menu>
```

**nav_graph.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/company_nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/companyProfileFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/companyProfileFragment"
        android:name="com.example.Companies.Fragments.CompanyProfileFragment"
        android:label="fragment_company_profile"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_company_profile" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/companyTeamFragment"
        android:name="com.example.Companies.Fragments.CompanyTeamFragment"
        android:label="fragment_company_team"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_company_team" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/companyDayOrdersFragment"
        android:name="com.example.Companies.Fragments.DayOrdersFragment"
        android:label="fragment_company_statistics"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_company_day_orders" />
</navigation>
```

and my activity where i'm using the BottomNavigation : **CompanyActivity**

```
public class CompanyActivity extends BaseActivity {


private BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_company);


    bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation_company);
    //set navHostFragment to bottomNav
    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.my_nav_host_fragment);
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(bottomNavigationView, navController);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the state of your fragment by overriding onSaveInstanceState():

```
@Override 
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    // Whatever is there to save
}
```

Comment: what do I have to put in the function?
in place of:
// Whatever is there to save

Comment: The current state of the fragment like if you have edit text you can store the text entered by the user etc.